# Refactoring ordinal number printing algorithm

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup

I'm working through Python Crash Course (end of Chapter 5). There is an example question to print the correct ending for the ordinal numbers 1 - 9, 1"st", 2"nd" etc. I expanded the example so it should work for any number, below.

How could this be written more concisely? What concepts could I look up? I'm an intermediate R user but quite new to Python. Thank you

```
nums = list(range(1, 50))

for i in nums:
    if i % 10 == 1 and i % 100 != 11:
        end = "st"
    elif i % 10 == 2 and i % 100 != 12:
        end = "nd"
    elif i % 10 == 3 and i % 100 != 13:
        end = "rd"
    else:
        end = "th"
    print(f"{i}{end}")
```

Comment: you can use dicitonary, where you can add the ones place as key and end value as value and exceptional case in it

Comment: Not exactly sure what concise is to mean here but DRY says `i % 10` and `i % 100` should be variabilized. Also `list(` isn't necessary for `range` if all you're doing is iterating over it. Other than these *I* think if-elif-else is the way to go, dictionary would mix things because of the presence of `!=` conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a `dict` can be used for lookup logic like this.  The complication is when the number's last two digits are in the "teens".  An example `dict` that would be useful in your case is:

```
endings = {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'}
```

And you could use it in the body of your `for` loop as such:

```
if 10 < i % 100 < 20:
    end = 'th'
else:
    end = endings.get(i % 10, 'th')  # The second arg to the `get` method returns a default value
```

Going another step further, you can make this even more concise by combining the lookup logic and taking advantage of logic short-circuiting:

```
end = endings.get(not 10 < i % 100 < 20 and i % 10, 'th')
```

***But I really don't recommend that!*** It's awfully yucky and confusing to the reader.

To be honest, your original example is the most readable among these options.  You have to weigh the value of conciseness vs readability before choosing what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative without as many if/else conditions

```
values_10 = [1, 2, 3]                                          # Numbers to equal mod 10
exceptions_100 = [11, 12, 13]                                  # Numbers not to equal mod 100
endings = ['st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th']                             # Set of endings
for i in range(1, 50):
    i_mod_10, i_mod_100 = i % 10, i % 100                      # Compute i mod 10 and i mod 100
    try:
        idx = values_10.index(i_mod_10)                        # Get index of match for 1, 2, or 3 (if exists)
        # Since no exception ending was 1, 2, or 3
        # end is based on whether i_mod_100 matches it's corresponding value
        end = endings[-1] if i_mod_100 == exceptions_100[idx] else endings[idx]  
    except ValueError:
        end = endings[-1]                                       # i_mod_10 was not 1, 2, or 3
    print(f"{i}{end}")
```